# Google Maps 3.x with jQuery UI 1.10.x issue

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-ui-tabs

I have created a test ASP.Net 4.0 application with Master \ Child page configuration to test some needed enhancements for our main application. I need to be able to put a google map inside a jQuery UI tab control. It will not be the first tab in the production version so I create a tab control with two tabs in the test app and put the map in the second tab. No matter what I did I could not get the map to display correctly in the second tab. As a test I move the map (just a div id="map-canvas" that jQuery attacks) into the first tab and walla - everything works fine - even after changing tabs and returning. Googled around a ton but cannot find a resolution for this one. Here is the map working in the first tab:

[image]

And here is the same map not working when placed in the second tab:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">    
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&sensor=false">
</script>
<link href="App_Themes/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>Map in Tab Control</h2>
<div id="mapTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">Tab-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">Tab-2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="a"><h2>This is the first tab</h2>            
    </div>
    <div id="b"><h2>This is the second tab</h2>          
        <div id="map-canvas" style="min-width:300px; min-height:300px;"></div>  
   </div>
</div>
```

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize(lt, ln) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            title: "Test Pin"
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mapTabs").tabs();
        var addr = '2626 East Oakland Park Blvd Oakland Park, FL 33306';
        var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var lat;
        var lon;
        gc.geocode({ 'address': addr }, function (results, status) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            initialize(lat, lon);
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but here's for anybody else with similar issues:

You'll need to call your map's initialize function.
Since you're using jquery, this should work:

```
$("#b").click(function() {
initialize();
});
```